# PHP - MYSQL: Does not recognize data in table

Tags: php, mysql

this is my code for a login system. I have a table called Users2 with the following columns: userID, prenume, nume, nicknamee, parola (which is password) and tara.
What I'm trying to do is this:
a user types in his username & password. clicks submit and after clicking submit he gets the message if he's connected

```
<form method="post">
Username: 
<input type="text" name="nicknameee" placeholder="Username">
<br> 
Password: 
<input type="password" name="passwordd" placeholder="Password">
<br> 
<input type="submit" name="Submit2" value="submit"> 
<br>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['Submit2'])) { 

    $result1 = $conn->query("SELECT nicknamee, parola FROM Users2 WHERE nicknamee='$_POST[nicknameee]' AND parola='$_POST[passwordd]' ");

    if (mysql_num_rows($result1)>0){
        echo "We are connected";
    }
    else{
        echo "INCORRECT";
    }

 } 
?>
</form>
```

The thing is I get this:

(the username and password form + submit button) and then:
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /home/u381189183/public_html/login.php on line 30
INCORRECT

Comment: Your code is open to sql injection, consider looking into mysqli and prepared statements

Comment: NEVER store passwords in plaintext in a database!! OMG are people still doing this? Use a hashing mechanism like php's `password_hash()` !

Comment: i started php about a week ago.. thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the result returned by the query is an `object` and not a resource you have to use `$result1->num_rows` in this case:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit2'])) { 

    $result1 = $conn->query("SELECT nicknamee, parola FROM Users2 WHERE nicknamee='$_POST[nicknameee]' AND parola='$_POST[passwordd]' ");

    if ($result1->num_rows > 0){
        echo "We are connected";
    }
    else{
        echo "INCORRECT";
    }

 }
```

Also you should switch to at least `mysqli`. Maybe `PDO`. And use prepared statements.

Comment: @OP is combining procedural and object oriented programming. (Just to clarify why to use num_rows and not mysql_num_rows)

Comment: Because the query returned result is an `object` and not an resource.

Comment: Ok, so far so good. So it works, thanks. But now I want to redirect the user to link.ext/loggedin.php in the if statement. How do I do that? Is it a html command or php command?

Comment: I refer to this

Comment: if ($result1->num_rows > 0){
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["isLoggedIn"] = 1;
  // redirect to link.link/loggedin.php
 }

Comment: Use `header('Location: loggedin.php');` in php.